# Converting .XLSX to .XLS in Python with win32com.client module

Tags: python, xls, xlsx, win32com

I am trying to find a way to convert many files from .xlsx to .xls and have been trying Python with the win32com.client module:

> ```
> import win32com.client
> xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
> wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\Kathleen\Desktop\Exp 1_1\A 1-1-1c.xlsx")
> wb.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\Kathleen\Desktop\Exp 1_1\A 1-1-1c.xls", FileFormat = 56)
> wb.Close()
> xl.Quit()
> ```

I have no error message but the converted file does not show up in the folder I have it set up for.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have Windows 7, 64 bit and have downloaded: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is wrong, your code works for me. I used a sample file and tested it, it works. Maybe try inserting print("Checking") and input() before and after the SaveAs command to check whether the save as command is executed or not.