# Python pywin32 TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I'm trying to call `CoCreateInstance`.  I get the error `TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID.`  I read in the docs that I need to create (I believe) an `IDispatch` object.  Trouble is it needs to be called on an `IPyUnknownObject` and I don't know how to get that.  Or am I off?

```
import pythoncom
import pywintypes


clsid = pywintypes.IID('{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}')  # CLSID_ShellWindow
iid = pywintypes.IID('{85CB6900-4D95-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85}')  # IID_IShellWindow
pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(clsid, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL, iid)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a list of all files from the selected Explorer Window with pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949747/return-a-list-of-all-files-from-the-selected-explorer-window-with-pywin32)