# Extract xlsx workbook file metadata/properties in python 3.6

Tags: python, metadata, openpyxl, xlsx

How can I read the properties/metadata like Title, Author, Subject, Last modified and Keywords stored in a xlsx file using Python? I've used **xlrd** library however, there are no such properties to extract theses entities. 
Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may be interested in [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

Something to get you started may look like:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
wb.properties
```

Here's the sample output:

```
<openpyxl.packaging.core.DocumentProperties object>
Parameters:
creator=u'User', title=None, description=None, subject=None, identifier=None,
language=None, created=datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 11, 9, 55, 2),
modified=datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 11, 10, 30, 38), lastModifiedBy=u'User',
category=None, contentStatus=None, version=None, revision=None, keywords=None,
lastPrinted=None
```

Is this something you can work with?

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking at `os` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html because the metadata are stored above the contents of your file level.
Example: `os.path.getmtime` gets you the last modified time.

Comment: This does not show the Excel metadata! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166006/1147688).