# How to get an Excel file's metadata?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Sorry for my English.
So I have a `.xlsx` (Excel) file. I need information about file.

For example:

- Who are authors?
- Last save by?
- and etc from right click on Excel file->Properties->Details->Origin

[image: screenshot of right-click menu]

I found a way how to read "Last save by".
For that I used

```
file = xlrd.open_workbook('path_to_file')
file.user_name
```

But I can't find how to get other information.

Comment: Duplicate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166006/1147688).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openpyxl, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930752/16157806.
The code provided by the author of the solution to that question is

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
wb.properties
```

Comment: Please don't use other people's answers. Instead, you can add a link to that answer in comments.

Comment: Use `print(wb.properties)` to see the list of properties that this holds.