# How to read Content Creation Date on an excel file metadata?

Tags: python, file, metadata

I'm trying to read Content Creation Date from an excel file using os Python module.
[Content Creation Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQvHe.png)

Is there a way to do so?

I've tried this code, but it doesn't return all the metadata from the file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
print(wb.properties)
```

Comment: `wb.properties.created` seems to be there?

Comment: yes, but it's the file Creation Date, I need the Content Creation date as shown in the image.

Comment: Okay... I see no reason the file creation date would be stored as metadata... that'd be purely for the filesystem to worry about... are you sure it's the file creation date and that it doesn't happen to be the content and file creation date are the same?

Comment: The difference between Content Creation Date and File Creation date is that if the excel file is copied the content creation date stays the same but the file creation date is set to the date the copy operation was made. That's why I need the Content Creation date, because it's more reliable.

Comment: Okay... so if you copy that excel file now to another file - `wb.properties.created` changes?

Comment: Surprisingly it didn't... I guess this it, but I need to test more to be sure. Are you certain that it's not the file creation date?

Comment: No... but like I said - how is the metadata of the workbook supposed to know what date the filesystem has for it? It'd be absolutely crazy for it *not* to be the content date

Answer (score 1):

To read the Excel *Metadata* use `openpyxl` like this:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def getExcelMetadata():

    excelFileName = 'test.xlsx'
    print('Retrieving Excel Metadata')
    wb = load_workbook(excelFileName)
    metaDate = wb.properties.created
    cDate = metaDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print('Data Retrieval Date  : {}'.format(cDate) )

getExcelMetadata()

# Data Retrieval Date  : 2022-07-14
```

---

The Excel Metadata is what's shown in the Excel Info:

[image]

---

**NOTE**

> The Excel metatdata creation date is not the same as what's shown by the OS.